# Flutter how to mock a call to rootBundle.loadString(...), then reset the mocked behavior?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

In my flutter code, I have logic that does this:

```
final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
```

And I have tests that I want to return a fake `AssetManifest.json` when this line is reached.

To mock it, I do this in the test:

```
ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
    .setMockMessageHandler('flutter/assets', (message) {
  final Uint8List encoded =
      utf8.encoder.convert('{"Foo.ttf":["Foo.ttf"]}');
  return Future.value(encoded.buffer.asByteData());
});
```

The weird thing is, this *works*, but any tests that run *after* it hang (they all get stuck in the code when it reaches the `await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json')` line.

I've tried adding

```
ServicesBinding.instance.defaultBinaryMessenger
    .setMockMessageHandler('flutter/assets', null);
```

But this doesn't seem to properly "clean up" the mocked behavior. In fact, if I run the above line in my `setUp`, the *first* test to run hangs.

So am I mocking the behavior wrong? Or am I not cleaning it up properly?

Comment: When you say that tests that run after it hang, do you mean other tests within the same group, other tests within the same file, or other tests from other files? I've noticed that while tests within the same group or file share some degree of state, placing tests in separate files completely isolates them from a state point of view. I know this is a workaround rather than a solution, but maybe it can help you.

Comment: Other tests within the same file! Any test after the test in question would hang. In the end, I chose to do what you suggested, to put the test in its own file.

Comment: Mocking not necessary here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72018321 , "This function will make your assets available for tests" .. unless the objective is specifically about running test code with only mocked rootBundle

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and believe it's due to caching by the bundle. This will cause the above test to fail, because the message never gets sent. When calling loadString, you can specify whether to cache the result. For example:

```
rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json', cache: false)
```

Note that if you use `loadStructuredData`, implementations can cache the result and you can't tell it not to.