# Flutter tests: `throwsA` followed by `ensureInitialized() + returnsNormally` breaks the test

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I'm unit testing a feature using Flutter tests and dividing tests by groups.

I've noticed that if I don't use `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` I get some error in the `fetchTripList` asynchronous method, so I wrote a test for it when FlutterBinding is not initialized (see the first group in the picture). It works fine as long as I do not initialize the FlutterBinding in the group `SetUp(...)`.

Then, in the next test group, I use the `ensureInitialized()` method so that `fetchTripList` returns normally. However, I get a TestFailure because it seems that FlutterBinding was not initialized... Moreover, subsequent similar tests that require FlutterBinding to be initialized succeed.

The "Null check operator ..." refers to an Exception thrown by `await rootBundle.loadString(...)` in the `fetchTripList` method.

Things I've tried:

- I've tried to comment out the first test group, and everything succeeded.
- I've tried to move the first test group at the end of the test suite, but that failed because FlutterBinding was already (and permanently) initialized.
- I've tried to remove the `late` + `setUp(...)` initialization in favor of a plain inline allocation/initialization, but nothing changed.

At this point, I'm guessing different options:

1. *returnsNormally* should not be wrapped by an `await expectLater(...)`
2. there is an alternative to `throwsA(...)` I could make use of
3. I should create a new file only for the first group (it's not something I'd like to do)

[image: Test suite screenshot]

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the issue or how to solve this riddle?

Answer (score 0):

After long research, I found the actual problem, and with it the solution.

It seems that when calling `await rootBundle.loadString(...)` the previous result is cached unless it is specified otherwise.
So I have solved the issue by telling the `loadString(...)` method to avoid caching, using the optional parameter "cache" this way: `await rootBundle.loadString(filePath, cache: false)`.

Big thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248271/7857364) answer for the hint!