# How to get result of rootBundle.loadString(key) during flutter widget test?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, integration-testing, assets, widget-test-flutter

I want to read a file from an asset during widget build with help of **rootBundle** but when I tried to call ***rootBundle.loadString('assets/myJsonAsset.json')*** like below :

```
testWidgets('load assets', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      final result = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/myJsonAsset.json');
      //above loadString method never return any result
      expect(result, isA<String>());
    });
```

then it causes the error :
[image]

`Unable to load asset: assets/myJsonAsset.json`

And the **rootBundle.loadString('assets/myJsonAsset.json')** never return any result.

Comment: Did you add assets path in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Yep, I think I need to mock rootBundle , But I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this line to be executed before your tests:

```dart
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

This function will make your assets available for tests

Comment: I also tried this but problem still exist, I think we need to find a way to mock the rootBundle service

Comment: This totally works - saved a lot of mocking headache, production code refactor, & time - Thanks!!