# How to mock asset file in flutter unit test project?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Let's say I have a file named **some_file.json** defined in pubspec.yaml as an asset. In my flutter project I load the file with the loadString function.

```
await rootBundle.loadString("some_file.json");
```

Then I read values from the file and I need to create Unit Tests. In the Unit Test project I create file with MemoryFileSystem class.

```
final MemoryFileSystem memoryFileSystem = MemoryFileSystem();
  
final File file = memoryFileSystem.file("some_file.json");
file.createSync(recursive: true);

expect(file.existsSync(), true);
```

The code above successfully creates file, but load method is not able to open the file.

Error:

> 237:7  PlatformAssetBundle.load
>
> Unable to load asset: build_resources/variables.json

Is there any better approach how to mock asset file in Unit Tests project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to mock a call to rootBundle.loadString(...), then reset the mocked behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60079645/flutter-how-to-mock-a-call-to-rootbundle-loadstring-then-reset-the-mocked)

Comment: I really don't see how to mock the file with that code.

Comment: The mocking code itself is contained in the question, not the answer. The second code block in the question is mocking the lookup of the asset